# leave a field blank in searchform

Tags: php, mysql

I have a searchform where you can search for properties. Right now it only works if you fill in all the fields. But how would I do if I want to eg leave a field blank and just search the rest, or just search one field and leave the rest blank?

This is the code for the query I have today:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM property
WHERE (rooms LIKE '%$room%' OR '$room' = '')
AND (status LIKE '%$status%' OR '$status' = '')
AND (type LIKE '%$type%' OR '$type' = '')
AND (adress LIKE '%$county%' OR '$county' = '')
AND (area LIKE '%$area%' OR '$area' = '')
AND (price BETWEEN '$min' AND '$max')
") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks in advance!

Maybe you should note that all the fields are select fields, not text fields.

Comment: Please use PDO or Mysqli, this query is vulnerable to sql injection. Mysql_* functions are also deprecated. To answer your question you will need either have a default value for your variables passed to your query or only build your query with the necessary filters; presumably you would do this with if statements.

Answer (score 3):

The way I typically do something like this is to only add the items to the WHERE clause that actually have a value set:

```
$sql_stmt = 'SELECT * FROM property';
$where_items = array();

if ($room != '') {
  $where_items[] = "(rooms LIKE '%$room') ";
}
if ($status != '') {
  $where_items[] = "(status LIKE '%$status') ";
}
// ... repeat for all optional variables ...

if (count($where_items) > 0) {
    $sql_stmt .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where_items);
}

$result = mysql_query($sql_stmt);
// ...
```

There are several ways to build up the query, but this one basically creates an array of items that will be ANDed together into the final query.

Comment: Just be careful; this is vulnerable to SQL injection as it is.

Comment: Agreed. This is a direct answer to the question, but does not address issues of SQL injection or deprecated methods. My personal recommendation is to use PDO and prepared statements (personal preference).